# document.referrer check for malicious code

Tags: php, security, verify, referer

I would like to assign a variable to be submitted with the form that passes the document.referrer value. I am using the below which works. However, I am concerned that someone could modify their document.referrer to insert malicious php code.

How could I first check that the document.referrer is a web address and not some other code before using it?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("prevurl").value=document.referrer;
}

</script>

<input id="prevurl" name="prevurl" type="hidden"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in validation on the client (at least security-wise, it can of course be a nice UX/usability feature in many cases). Any checks you implement for the referer (regardless now whether that makes sense at all), an attacker can just remove that from the javascript, or plainly post any value for the form variable. Validation needs to be server-side.

On the server, receiving any input (including a string which happens to be valid php or whatever else if evaluated) is safe. It's **what you do with it** that can be a problem. You have to be careful and keep in mind that anything that comes from a request is user input, and a malicious user could have sent anything. You obviously don't want to eval() it as php, you don't want to use it in SQL queries without taking care of SQL injection, you don't want to write it back to a page unencoded (that would be one form of XSS), you don't want your access control decisions be directly based on user input, etc.

But only receiving (even storing) it *is* ok.

Comment: I see. Thank you for that explanation.